# AS3 - Detect timeline code inside loaded SWF files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swfloader

I'm investigating legacy project. Many SWF files are loaded dynamicaly. I've founded that some of them has code on frames. Cause of this I get unexpected behaviour in my application. Is there way to detect this code (it can be in symbol linked to AS also)?

Comment: As I already answered you in the other thread, you can explore (and, actually, edit) the content of SWF files with JPEXS tool: https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/

Comment: Problem is, that I get config with file list from back-end. When marketing guys add some sale-event - new SWF files would be loaded. And this assets are made by outsource designer team and I haven`t their contacts. I need some tool to recognize timeline code inside unpredictable SFW in runtime. Or even disable any timeline code in child SWF with some rule.

Comment: You can set this property to **false**, I think: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#allowCodeImport In general, you can load the other SWF into separate security sandbox and separate application domain so it will not be able to interfere with the main app contents and structure.